# Copying the value of a pointer to another pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers, copy, command

I would like to copy the value stored in `char *command` to a `char *command_copy`, because I am performing tokenization on `command` but still would like to use the initial command (which is why I am creating a copy). The problem is that every time I try something, the whole program goes crazy and I just can't find where to start or what to do.

Here is my code:

```c
int main(void)
{
    init_ui();
    hist_init(100);

    char *command;
    while (true) {
        signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
        command = read_command();
        if (command == NULL) {
            break;
        }
        char *command_copy;
        command_copy = (char *) malloc(1000);
        memcpy(command_copy, command, sizeof(*command));
        char *args[4096];
        int tokens = 0;
        char *next_tok = command;
        char *curr_tok;
        while((curr_tok = next_token(&next_tok, " \t\n\r")) != NULL) {
            if(strncmp(curr_tok, "#", 1) == 0){
                break;
            }
            args[tokens++] = curr_tok;
        }
        args[tokens] = NULL;

        if(args[0] == NULL) {
            continue;
        }

        hist_add(command);

        int builtin_status = handle_builtins(tokens, args);
        if(builtin_status == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        pid_t child = fork();
        if(child == -1){
            perror("fork");
        }
        ...
```

I would like the `hist_add()` function to take `command_copy` instead of `command` because `command` at that point in the code is only the first word of the whole initial command, and I would like `hist_add()` to have the whole (original) command.

read_command(void):

```
char *read_command(void)
{
    if(scripting == true) {
        ssize_t read_sz = getline(&line, &line_sz, stdin);
        if(read_sz == -1){
            perror("getline");
            free(line);
            return NULL;
        }
        line[read_sz - 1] = '\0';
        return line;
    }
    else {
        return readline(prompt_line());
    }
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(*command)` is equivalent to `sizeof(char)`, which is defined to `1`. `strcpy()` or safer `strncpy()` may be useful instead of the `memcpy()`.

Comment: When I try strcpy() or strncpy() the program is segfaulting, what could be the cause for this?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, what does `read_command()` return?

Comment: Just updated the code with read_command(), it returns a pointer

Comment: Debuggers (`gdb` for example) are useful to find which line is causing Segmentation Fault.

Comment: Using valgrind tells me it is creating memory issues, I tried strdup and it works great for history. But I might be lost with memory somewhere, am I supposed to just use this: char *command_copy = strdup(command); and no malloc? no free()?

Comment: So adding free(command_copy); all the way at the end should solve it

Comment: Sadly it does not :/

Comment: Add the `free()` call *inside* the `while(true)` loop (at the end of that). Otherwise, you'll only be freeing the last copy allocated, and all those from previous loops will be left 'hanging', giving your memory leaks reported by valgrind.

Comment: This is what valgrind gives me with freeing at the end of the while loop: https://imgur.com/6DUUWPN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a copy of a `char*` string - *so long as that string is properly `nul`-terminated* - you can use the [`strdup` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup). This, essentially, is a combination of `malloc` and `strcpy`.

So, you can use something like this:

```c
while (looping) {
    char* original = getstring();
    char* copy = strdup(original);
    // ...
    // do whatever you want with "original" - "copy" is left alone!
    //
    free(copy); // When you're done, free the copy
}
```

The `strdup` call is equivalent to the following:

```c
    char* copy = malloc(strlen(original) + 1);
    strcpy(copy, original);
```